# Getting an ACPI BIOS error while booting fromm the live usb of Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on a dell inspiron 5000

Tags: 18.04, budgie

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie on a dell inspiron 5000 non-gaming laptop without the NVDIA graphics card. When I select try without install option I get a black screen with errors before the Budgie UI shows up. Should I go ahead with the install or do I need to do something so that these errors don't show up during the actual installation. (I am scared since I am going to delete my Windows 10 and install ubuntu, I like a single boot)

[error screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIm8c.jpg)

Comment: Did you verify your ISO download? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and write to install media? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  (CD refers to whatever media you wrote ISO to, be it CD/ DVD/thumb-drive/hdd/ssd/..)

Comment: Could you fix it? I'm dealing with the same issue. I've verified the ISO download both for 18.04 and 19.10 and none of them will boot.